# iMac 27" late 2009 running OSX 10.10.4 - please explain time machine to me?

Tags: time-machine

I hope you can explain this to me.  I have a 1 TB hard drive on my iMac.  I bought a 2TB external drive for time machine.  It says that it makes backups hourly, daily, and monthly...and then deletes old backups when the disc is full.  Well, I had to wipe my external hard drive and start over tonight because I just kept getting the message that time machine couldn't back up my computer because it was full.  Is my 2TB external drive too small?  It's double the size of my computer hard drive...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Two TB should be more than enough. It's a good idea to start with an empty HDD, so if you had any data on it; that could be the problem is. It could also be because the drive was configured for Windows OS.

If you want to use the HDD as time machine and to store other stuff you should partition it. It's simple just open Disk Utility, select the disk, go on partition tap, and the plus button. Make sure the format is Mac OS Extended, then make the new partition of about 1.5 TB. After it's done, you should see two drives connected. The old one (0.5 TB) should still contain all your data from before if it was less than 0.5 TB. You can just format the new one if you like. Then just restart the Time Machine process; from Time Machine Preferences Pane > Select Drive.

You also configure which file you don't want to backup, things which you can just download again, from the options button in Pref Pane.

Comment: Thanks.  No, I'm not doing anything with the drive but Time Machine.

Answer (score 0):

2 TB is a lot, but, though the initial backup is only 1 TB at most, your Mac will be making daily backups of your files, while keeping the old versions around in case you would want to restore them. Even if you deleted a file off of your Mac, the copy(s) Time Machine made will still exist, (each) taking up space on the Time Machine drive. So, you can see how even 2 TB drive can fill up pretty quickly this way.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I assumed it would fill up fast...I just thought it would delete old files with new ones...not say "your hard drive is full".  I thought an extra TB would be enough for that.